# Switching between circuits, transistor-based SPDT?

Tags: transistors, switches

I want to use a piezo buzzer alternatively as a sound detector and as a sound emitter, on the same circuit (be gentle, this is my first attempt to electronics since the university long years ago).

I want the piezo to monitor the ambiant sound level, then emit sound for a while when the sound level is above a given threshold (typically, play music when baby cries during the night).  I'll use an Arduino for the processing part.

For the sound detector part, I plan to reproduce [NerdKits' tutorial](http://www.nerdkits.com/videos/sound_meter/).  I hear the sound emitter part is much more simple as far as electronics is concerned (just plug the buzzer between input and ground, is that it ?), and I don't fear the programming part.

Now what bothers me is how to switch between the receiver/emitter setups.  I understand I'm looking for a kind of transistor-based SPDT.  Is a push-pull setup the way to go, or am I on the wrong track ?

NB : Yes, I could just use a second piezo buzzer or whatever, but I find it somehow more satisfying to use the same device both for input and output, provided it's doable.

Comment: There are some piezo buzzers that are self-resonant, and contain some other stuff so they buzz when simply connected to a voltage. However, these won't work for also being a sound detector.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit you are (will be) building is this one which is a pretty standard one transistor amplifier and they go through its design step by step.
[image]

The makers of the ceramic buzzer give a number of driver circuits, the simplest is this one which can be driven by an external oscillator (e.g 555 astable, cmos multivibrator etc.) or a pin from a microcontroller.

[image]

To combine the two circuits just use a simple SPDT switch. Sometimes using transistors as switches over complicates the design.

You only need a transistor switch if you are going to change over the function by some remote device.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I thought I needed no additional components for the piezo to buzz.  However I'm afraid I don't get your suggestion concerning the SPDT in your diagram.  What will make it switch ?  The point of my project would be to make the switch automatically (for a given period) when the piezo detects sound.  But if I understand it correctly, isn't the SPDT switched manually in your suggestion ?

Comment: You could make the switch a spdt relay and operate that with a timer.